# Can someone indentify this font

Tags: fonts

I am pretty new to latex and have seen a paper which font I would like to use. I think some of the advance users will recognize it in a minute or so. Can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Peter[image: font example]

Comment: if you have the pdf, then  acrobat or the pdffonts utility will show all the fonts in the document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have the pdf indeed. Acrobat shows multiple fonts, the first is ArialMT. However when I use the arialmt.sty in latex, the font in the output file is different than showed in the image. Helvetica is also shown as a font, which is also a font in LaTeX right?

Comment: Arial/Helvetica are sans serif fonts, while your image shows a serif font, surely there are more fonts in the list? By the way, some general answers to questions like this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture

Comment: arial/helevtical are sans serif, clearly the fonts shown are not those

Comment: Yes there are more fonts in the list. Maybe this is easier (a link to the pdf file as the paper is online available): https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjhzL2nmNHPAhXGCMAKHfKwAJsQFggpMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fthesis.eur.nl%2Fpub%2F18446%2FStraathof-328857.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFJJTpUeR_zznypAdRn0hkmO5dHvA&sig2=pIvj4hSqz8AFwFAUpkbSVQ

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the standard font (Computer Modern):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
This paper sheds some light on the role of cross-border capital flows in the
post-2008 divergence of sovereign bond yields within the European Monetary
Union (EMU). I identify a fragility of monetary union sovereign debt,
focusing on the inability of sovereign nations to control their own currency
in combination with a large capital outflow.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Update:**

The PDF of the OP confirms it, both fonts `CMR10` and `CMBX12` (section title) are present among the fonts of the OP: mostly Computer Modern and Helvetica/ArialMT as sans-serif font, not shown in the image of the question.

Comment: It is, according to his linked PDF.

Comment: I thought it looked like cm:-)

Comment: Thank you! So in order to get almost the same style as the paper I have posted, I should not do anything regarding to the font (as Computer Modern is the standard)?

Comment: @peter Yes. (In case of many accented letters, the Latin Modern fonts (kind of successor of Computer Modern) like `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{lmodern}` would be a choice.